# Can't start mysql service

Tags: opensuse, mysql, systemd, services

Trying to start my mysql service.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

returns:

```
Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.
```

Further:

```
systemctl status mysql.service
```

returns:

```
mysql.service - LSB: Start the MySQL database server
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
      Active: failed since Mon, 04 Aug 2014 16:20:43 -0400; 38s ago
     Process: 14148 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Process: 16457 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/mysql.service
```

Any ideas how I can find out what's happening?

That latest entry in `/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log`:

```
140805 08:52:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140805  8:52:42 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
140805  8:53:13 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Could not get an exclusive lock; file is probably in use by another process' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_contr$
140805  8:53:13 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
140805  8:53:13 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140805  8:53:13 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
140805  8:53:13 [ERROR] Aborting

140805  8:53:13 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140805 08:53:13 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysql/mysqld.pid ended
```

Comment: Look in your MySQL logs. Their location may vary in different distros, but start looking in `/var/log/mysql`.  You'll probably need to be `root` to access it.  Post anything useful in your question.

Comment: Have you ever setup mysql (run `mysql_secure_installation` as root)?

Comment: @SailorCire Yes, I believe that is what I did.

Comment: @garethTheRed Please see my edit.

Comment: It's telling you it can't start because the control file is opened by another process.  Run `lsof /var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control` and it should tell you what has it open.  On my system that file is opened by `mysqld`.

Comment: @garethTheRed I think that was the problem because I had `kill`ed the mysql service, but it wasn't a clean shutdown. I restarted the VM and it is working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control` file is open by another process and consequently, `mysqld` fails to start.

Check who/what is currently has the file open with:

```
lsof `/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control`
```

It should list the process(es) that has it open.

```
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
mysqld  1506 mysql   10uW  REG  253,1       52 263948 /var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control
```

If the process definitely shouldn't be running, then shut it down with:

```
sudo kill -SIGTERM <PID>
```

If that fails:

```
sudo kill -SIGKILL <PID>
```

Or reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `/etc/my.cnf` file, and check the `datadir` and `tmpdir` variables.  Go to those directories, and check the permissions of the files within them.  If there's any file owned by `root`, change the permissions to something like `mysql:mysql` and try again.

---

Example:

In `/etc/my.cnf` you found:

```
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
```

Try the following and then try to start mysql again:

```
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: That is the same directory for `datadir` in my `my.cnf`. Everything in that directory is owned by mysql user and mysql group except for the directory itself and a subdirectory (`/var/lib/mysql/mysql`) that is owned by the mysql user and root group with `drwx------` permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `mysql_install_db` script in packages `mariadb-server-5.5.34-2.fc20` and `community-mysql-server-5.5.35-1.fc20`. It does not set up proper permissions on server data directory. Run following command as `root` to fix it:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

credits to:
https://www.moucha.cc/charon/tag/mariadb/

Answer (score 0):

Had this error on my Raspberry Pi. Went to `/var/lib/mysql` and found a file named `raspberrypi.err`. In it I saw that during startup it found a line in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` that it didn't like. The offending line in my case was `bind-address` but it might be a good place to start looking.